# IMAP Command for UID and MessageSize list

Tags: c#, .net, imap

Writing a small portion of IMAP functionality in a c# .net application that basically lists all UIDS and their corresponding message sizes. I've looked at the IMAP RFC and can't find an ideal solution to get this info.

My approach:

1. I use a combination of UID SEARCH ALL to give me all the UIDS, which
   is fast.
2. Then I try to get all headers and read the size from that.

Step 2, is too slow - seems a bit silly to download the entire header, just to get the message size.

Is there a simple and/or fast solution for getting the list of UIDS and corresponding Message Sizes in a single command? If not, is there a much faster way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMAP server provides various options in fetch command, u can use the following command to fetch mail size and corresponding uid as well

> a1 fetch uid 1:* RFC822.SIZE

for more reference:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5

Comment: Tried this: FETCH 1:* (FLAGS UID RFC822.SIZE) and UID FETCH 1:* (FLAGS UID RFC822.SIZE), didn't work. Get 3 BAD response error. Please advise.

Comment: Didn't select a specific mailbox hence, the command wasn't working. After selecting a mailbox, all works well! Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.